# How to Watch a Domain

Tags: dns

I know this isn't a programming question, but it is related to the web, so I thought someone might know.

I would like a couple of domain names, but the ones I want are registered. Is there any program or website that  can automatically watch to see if this domain name loads, and if it doesn't, send me an e-mail?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you know it isn't a programming question, why did you post it?

Comment: this kind of question should be asked on webmasters.stackexchange.com (it will probably be migrated soon, please don't ask it twice)

Comment: We already have over two million questions here that are about the subject we are interested in, and we'd kinda like to stick to programming questions. Thanks.

Comment: Goes beyond monitoring: some provider offer a backorder service, means they will register the domain the moment it is available.

Comment: Didn't know where to look, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/domainaddon/domain-alert.aspx) offers this kind of watching.

[EDIT] This was treated in [thread](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7867/monitoring-domain-availability)